# Parameter not passing in correctly

Tags: c++, function, directx, direct3d

I have a function like the following:

```
void Direct3DRenderer::CreatePrimitive(char *name, Direct3DHelper::VERTEX vertices[])
{
    LPDIRECT3DVERTEXBUFFER9 vertex_buf;

    d3d_dev->CreateVertexBuffer(4 * sizeof(Direct3DHelper::VERTEX), 0, Direct3DHelper::FVF, D3DPOOL_MANAGED, &vertex_buf, NULL);

    VOID *pVoid;
    vertex_buf->Lock(0, 0, (void**)&pVoid, 0);
    memcpy(pVoid, vertices, sizeof(vertices));
    vertex_buf->Unlock();

    primitiveMap[name] = vertex_buf;
}
```

For some reason that sizeof(vertices) is not giving me the right value, or something. This is what I'm inputting:

```
Direct3DHelper::VERTEX verticesA[] =
{
    { 0, 0, 0, 1, D3DCOLOR_XRGB(255, 0, 0) },
    { 10, 0, 0, 1, D3DCOLOR_XRGB(0, 255, 0) },
    { 0, 10, 0, 1, D3DCOLOR_XRGB(255, 255, 0) },
    { 10, 10, 0, 1, D3DCOLOR_XRGB(0, 0, 255) }
};
```

If I don't pass it into the function and just replace all the "vertices" with "verticesA," it works... Please help.

Comment: Note that [Clang](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/472ac49e538386e6) and [GCC](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/489c2b99c1856a4f) both warn about this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The use of the `[]` syntax does not mean you are passing an array.  It's still a pointer, which makes it all the more confusing to use.

So sizeof `vertices` in your function will be sizeof `Direct3DHelper::VERTEX*`.

You'll need to pass the size of the array into the function from where it was created.  Only in the scope where it was created will the size account for the whole size of the array.

I would actually recommend using something like `std::array` or `std::vector`.

Comment: Could you show an example? This is my structure by the way:
    struct VERTEX
 {
  float x, y, z, rhw;
  DWORD color;
 };

Comment: I'm new to C++, coming from Java, it's very different.

Comment: Nevermind figured it out. Thank you for your help.

Comment: Actually not. It seems that I can't get the size of my vector after passing it in as an argument.

Comment: Should just be able to do `vector_variable.size()`.  If you can't then something's going on I'm not aware of.